# Format for using chisq.test in R using only observed count and expected count data

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how to use the chi.sq test in R using only the observed count and expected count data.

For example, say I've observed that in a total population of birds, there are 12 pairs of parent-offspring (PO) pairing, 24 pairs of full-sibling (FS) pairing, and 8 pairs of first-cousin (FC) pairings. I have calculated the expected counts for each type of pairing to be 1 pair of parent-offspring pairing, 4 pairs of full-sibling pairing, and 9 pairs of first-cousin pairings.

```
                      PO     FS     FC
     Observed Count   12     24     8
     Expected Count    1      4     9
```

I only know how to use the function by using the observed counts and the expected proportions, but if I do it that way with this example, it doesn't work because my expected proportions do not add up to 1, and that is because these types of pairings (PO, FS, FC) do not represent the entire population of birds, there are other types of pairings that I am not looking at here.

Comment: The expected counts should add to the observed counts. How did you do this calculation?

Comment: This is a made up example, so I didn't really make any calculation for this specifically. Say the bird population has a total of 50 birds but not all of them are considered either a PO, FS, or FC pairing, which is why the observed counts add up to 44 and not 50. The missing 6 are considered another type of pairing that I am not looking at here. Same goes for the expected count, which only adds up to 14. I expect 14 birds out of 50 to be either PO, FS, or FC pairing, but I actually see 44. That's why the observed and the expected counts total don't equal. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Either you need to add the 4th category (if you want to compare the distribution across all 4 categories) which will make the sums even or you would need to compute the expected counts conditional on only being in the PO/FS/FC categories (ie, the expected counts for 44 individuals given they can only be in those three categories).

Comment: If the total observed counts did equal the total expected counts, is there a way to use the chisq.test in R with just using the observed and expected counts?

Comment: The test statistic would then simply be `sum((obs - expected)^2/expected)`